# to refer .net dll from different folder than the exe directory

Tags: c#

I have a structure:-
     `\bin\debug\abc.exe`  and 
     `\Libs\win32\xyz.dll`.
Now I need to refer `xyz.dll` so as to run my `abc.exe`. I tried with "probing" tag in `app.config` but in that case the possibility was only when I had `'Libs`' folder in '`debug`' folder i.e. where `.exe` is present. But I want to come 2 folders out from .exe and then go into `\Libs\win32` to refer to .dll . Please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: Use Reflection to Load Assembly

Comment: Invoking this kind of DLL Hell intentionally is very unwise and the CLR does its best to help you avoid shooting your foot off.  Defeating it requires the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, use Assembly.LoadFrom() in your event handler for that event.  Make sure it isn't required in your Main() method yet.

Answer (score 3):

One option is handling `AssemblyResolve` event, every time .NET couldn't find required assembly in current path, it will trigger `AssemblyResolve` event:

```
{
    // Execute in startup
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;
}

private Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string RESOURCES = ".resources";
    try
    {
        /* Extract assembly name */
        string[] sections =  args.Name.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        if (sections.Length == 0) return null;

        string assemblyName = sections[0];

        /* If assembly name contains ".resource", you don't need to load it*/
        if (assemblyName.Length >= RESOURCES.Length &&
                assemblyName.LastIndexOf(RESOURCES) == assemblyName.Length - RESOURCES.Length)
        {
            return null;
        }

        /* Load assembly to current domain (also you can use simple way to load) */
        string assemblyFullPath = "..//..//Libs//" + assemblyName;
        FileStream io = new FileStream(assemblyNameWithExtension, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        if (io == null) return null;
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(io);
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)io.Length));

        return assembly;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {}
}
```

*Another option is loading all of your required assemblies to current domain at your project start-up.

Answer (score 0):

You use ..\ in the file path to move up a directory.
So if you're in **\bin\debug\abc.exe** then your reference to **\Libs\win32\xyz.dll** would be

```
..\..\Libs\win32\xyz.dll
```

This should only be necessary when building your projects, when it's built if your executable is referencing the dll correctly it only needs to be put in the same folder as the dll.

Unless of course you're using dllimport or something where you need to know the exact path of the dll during runtime.

Comment: But where should I use this path. <probing> tag in app.confog does not work with such path because it can only refer to subfolders.

Comment: No but I need to refer dll from different folder only when I run my exe

Comment: How exactly are you using this dll, is it a normal .NET project reference or Win32 dll or something? Is there a reason why you don't copy it into the same folder or a subfolder with your .exe during the build?

Comment: Its a normal .Net dll. The reason is that we are making same project in java also. So when we give to client we want that exe for .net and jar for java be in one folder and all dependent dlls in other folder. Plz suggest something. The above code didn't work for me